# Using pandas dataframes, how to read through a column to find "True" statement and then proceed to create a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Below I have 4 columns in my dataframe. I am interested in going through the entire "Greater_than_50" column. Upon reaching a "True" flag, I then want to take the associated  "Discharge" and "Resistance" values to make a new dataframe which contains only those values found to be "True".

```
time           Discharge          Resistance  Greater_than_50
-------------------------------------------------------------
0                  0.000                 NaN              NaN
1                  0.005              76.373             True
2                  0.010             -48.174            False
3                  0.016             -37.012            False
4                  0.021             -27.808            False
5                  0.026             -24.674            False
6                  0.031             -20.464            False
7                  0.037             100.114            True
...                  ...                 ...              ...
```

I would like the new dataframe to look something like this:

```
Discharge          Resistance  
------------------------------
0.005              76.373 
0.037             100.114          
...                   ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Greater_than_50'] = [val.strip() for val in df['Greater_than_50'].astype(str)]

# columns to keep
col_mask = ['Discharge', 'Resistance']

df_new = df.loc[df['Greater_than_50'] == 'True'][col_mask]
```

This is how I tested it:

```
'''
time    Discharge   Resistance  Greater_than_50
0   0.000   NaN NaN
1   0.005   76.373  True
2   0.010   -48.174 False
3   0.016   -37.012 False
4   0.021   -27.808 False
5   0.026   -24.674 False
6   0.031   -20.464 False
7   0.037   100.114 True
'''

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

print(df)
```

Original df:

```
   time  Discharge  Resistance Greater_than_50
0     0      0.000         NaN             NaN
1     1      0.005      76.373            True
2     2      0.010     -48.174           False
3     3      0.016     -37.012           False
4     4      0.021     -27.808           False
5     5      0.026     -24.674           False
6     6      0.031     -20.464           False
7     7      0.037     100.114            True
```

.

```
df['Greater_than_50'] = [val.strip() for val in df['Greater_than_50'].astype(str)]

# columns to keep
col_mask = ['Discharge', 'Resistance']

df_new = df.loc[df['Greater_than_50'] == 'True'][col_mask] 
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
   Discharge  Resistance
1      0.005      76.373
7      0.037     100.114
```

Just replace whatever columns you want to keep in the 'col_mask'.

Comment: Thank you sir. You suggestion appears to have worked. How do you recommend I drop the extra columns. I would like the new dataframe to display only the "Discharge" and "Greater_than_50" columns.

Comment: Updated my answer to drop other columns

Comment: do you mean only 'Discharge' and 'Resistance' columns or "Discharge" and "Greater_than_50"

Comment: Nevermind, just replace whatever columns you want to keep in the 'col_mask'.

Comment: My apologies. You are correct. Only  'Discharge' and 'Resistance' columns.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If it helped you, consider marking it as Answer and also upvote to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the positions of columns "Discharge" and "Resistance" are 1 and 2, `df2` is what you need

```
df1 = df[df.Greater_than_50 == True]
df2 = df1.iloc[:, 1:3]
```

You can do a one liner like so

```
df2 = df[df.Greater_than_50 == True].iloc[:, 1:3]
```

Comment: I attempted to run this and I got this error:

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Discharge', 'Resistance'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Comment: I guess that's a problem with indexing, I've updated my answer to use iloc instead of loc, let me know if it works now.

Comment: This fixed the index issue, but did not return the results I was expecting. Thank you anyway.